# How to create a koalas dataframe with index from another dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-koalas

How can I create a koalas dataframe with index from another dataframe? I can do this in pandas but I am struggling to achieve the same in koalas. Following are my attempts so far:

```
from databricks import koalas as pd
import pandas
```

pandas (works):

```
dft = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]}, index=dft.index)
```

koalas (fails with error):

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]}, index=dft.index)
output:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2826623/2112004205.py in <module>
      1 dft = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
----> 2 dft1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]}, index=dft.index)

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    517                 pdf = data
    518             else:
--> 519                 pdf = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    520             internal = InternalFrame.from_pandas(pdf)
    521 

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    612         elif isinstance(data, dict):
    613             # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 614             mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    615         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    616             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    462         # TODO: can we get rid of the dt64tz special case above?
    463 
--> 464     return arrays_to_mgr(
    465         arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy
    466     )

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    119             index = _extract_index(arrays)
    120         else:
--> 121             index = ensure_index(index)
    122 
    123         # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in ensure_index(index_like, copy)
   6334     else:
   6335 
-> 6336         return Index(index_like, copy=copy)
   6337 
   6338 

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name, tupleize_cols, **kwargs)
    482                     data = list(data)
    483 
--> 484                 if data and all(isinstance(e, tuple) for e in data):
    485                     # we must be all tuples, otherwise don't construct
    486                     # 10697

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/indexes/base.py in __bool__(self)
   2605 
   2606     def __bool__(self) -> bool:
-> 2607         raise ValueError(
   2608             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   2609             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(self.__class__.__name__)

ValueError: The truth value of a Int64Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

pandas (works):

```
dft = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]})
dft1.index=dft.index
print(dft1)
output:
     a  c
11   2  3
12  21  4
13  31  5
```

koalas (fails without error):

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]})
dft1.index=dft.index
print(dft1)
output:
    a   c
0   2   3
1   21  4
2   31  5
print(dft1.index)
output: Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a hacky solution for now. If someone has a better solution please let me know:

```
dft = dft = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = dft1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]})

index = dft.index
index = index.to_series()
index = index.reset_index(drop=True)

pd.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames',True)
dft1['r'] = index
dft1 = dft1.set_index('r',drop=True)
dft1.index.name = dft.index.name
pd.reset_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames')
dft1
output:
    a   c
11  2   3
12  21  4
13  31  5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dft = ps.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[0,1,0]},index=[11,12,13])
dft1 = ps.DataFrame({'a':[2,21,31],'c':[3,4,5]}, index=dft.index.tolist())
dft1
```

out：

```
    a   c
11  2   3
12  21  4
13  31  5
```